# How do I use egrep to list words that match a regular expression?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, expression, grep

I need to use egrep to count words that contain strings which match a regular expression. For instance, I need to do something like "Count the number of words containing three consecutive vowels" (not exactly that, but that's the gist of it).

I've figured out how to do it to count lines which contain these words, but when I add the -w tag I get an `egrep: illegal option -- w` error.

Here's the regular expression I'd use to count lines in the scenario above, which seems to work:

```
egrep -i -c '[aeiou][aeiou][aeiou]' full.html
```

Using the `-w` tag with this command causes the error I listed above, even if I add \b tags around the regex expression. e.g.:

```
egrep -i -c -w '\b.*[aeiou][aeiou][aeiou].*\b' full.html
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm running this on Solaris 10 out of the terminal.

Comment: I dunno, but `[a|e|i|o|u]{3}` would be easier to read

Comment: No need for the pipes in character classes, just use `[aeiou]{3}`.

Comment: I've edited my post to make it easier to read.

Comment: Adding the `{3}` tag causes my commands to return counts of 0. Again, I'm running this on Solaris 10, not Linux or Unix.

Answer (score 5):

use this way also to find the count of the words that contains strings

`grep --color -Eow '[aeiou][aeiou][aeiou]' filename | wc -l`

or

`egrep -ow '[aeiou][aeiou][aeiou]' filename | wc -l`

o for Print only the matched.

w for word.

finally, it will display the count of the word.

Comment: This is a good answer for 'list words consisting of ...' rather than 'containing ...'  Combine this answer with the regex from @shellter's answer and you have a winner.

Comment: If `grep -o -c` works for you, it's preferrable to `grep -o | wc -l` but at least GNU `grep` had a long-standing bug for this option combination. I believe it should be fixed in GNU Coreutils 8.x.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to consult your solaris man-pages to know if your egrep supports any/all/some of the GNU like extensions.

Does your system have /usr/xpg4/bin ? If yes, make sure your MANPATH includes /usr/xpg4/man. That dir used to have the newest versions, short of having something like /opt/gnu install added.

In any case, your regexp `'\b.*[aeiou][aeiou][aeiou].*\b'` reads to my eye as ...

```
1 word-boundary
followed by any number of any chars (including blanks and vowels) 
followed by three vowels, 
followed by any number of any chars (including blanks and vowels), 
followed by 1 word-boundary.
```

Probably not what your really want.

To meet your need of words with 3 vowels in a row and using old/square reg-ex long hand, try

```
 egrep -i -c '[a-z]*[aeiou][aeiou][aeiou][a-z]*' full.html
```

This says, match chars [a-z] any number (including none), before 3 vowels, followed by any number of chars [a-z] (including none). So space chars won't match [a-z]. YOu're using -i to ignore case, so you don't have to use `[A-Za-z]`. Obviously, if you find other chars that you want to consider as word chars, maybe the `'_'` char?, add that to both sides.

Sorry, but I'm going from memory here, I don't work in a Solaris shop, and can't test it there.

**edit**

Also note that the man page on my current system for grep says

```
  -c, --count
          Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching  lines
          for  each  input  file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see
          below), count non-matching lines.
```

Note it's the number of matching lines, not the number of matches.

Might be easier to use

```
  awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /.*[aeiou][aeiou][aeiou].*/) cnt++};}; END{print "count="cnt}'file
```

IHTH

Comment: `\b` is the tag used to define word boundaries, similar to `\<` and `\>` in vim. I still haven't solved the problem. Might just have to use awk.

Comment: ok, word-boundaries now used in description of your search. What does your man page say for --count? "count of matching lines" or something else? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that egrep does not support `\b` for word boundaries. Try `\<` for beginning of word boundary and `\>` for end of word boundary.

**EDIT**
Hmm... never mind. According to the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?egrep) `\b` is supported.

Actually, I think the answer is that only grep supports the "-w" option. I don't think egrep does.
http://ss64.com/bash/egrep.html

Comment: I believe those are the tags for vim, not egrep, but maybe I'm wrong. It still doesn't work, anyway.

Comment: It still returns the entire line when using grep.

Answer (score 0):

Which platform and which version of egrep?

The -w option works for me (CentOS and Mac with GNU egrep) - see below.  Also, `\b` works as expected - see below.

Also, I used a different regex - see below.

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1

$ cat test.txt 
this and that iou and eai
not this aaih
not this haai

$ egrep -i -w '[aeiou]{3}' test.txt 
this and that iou and eai

# with no -w
egrep -i '\b[aeiou]{3}\b' test.txt
this and that iou and eai

# with neither -w nor {3}
$ egrep -i '\b[aeiou][aeiou][aeiou]\b' /tmp/test.txt 
this and that iou and eai

# using '\<' and '\>' works as well for word boundaries
$ egrep -i '\<[aeiou][aeiou][aeiou]\>' /tmp/test.txt 
this and that iou and eai
```

Comment: I'm running it on Solaris 10.

Comment: Calling `pkginfo -l SUNWcsu | grep "VERS"` gives me a result of



`VERSION:  11.10.0,REV=2005.01.21.16.34`

Comment: You should be able to install the GNU grep package.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to Solaris.  But this works as well (with no -w): `egrep -i '\b[aeiou]{3}\b' test.txt`

Comment: Nothing I've tried has worked. I'm on Cygwin now, and it still returns lines instead of individual words, even when I use the `-w` tag with `\b` in the regex expression. I even tried `\<`. This is starting to get frustrating. I don't understand why the same commands that work above don't work here.

Comment: Is there just no way to return the individual words? I don't want the whole line to be returned. I am running GNU grep.

Comment: `grep -o` prints each individual match on a separate line. If there are multiple matches on the same line, it prints each on a separate output line.