# How do i create classes of the same output in grep?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I'm trying to find out the number of different three vowel combinations in several languages. Using grep I have isolated occurrences of three vowels in text files. This is the code I used:

```
'[aeuioj]{3}' *file name* -o
```

I have found that people have done this before, see link below

[How do I use egrep to list words that match a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644074/how-do-i-use-egrep-to-list-words-that-match-a-regular-expression)

Only now I need to filter all repetitions out of the output, which should leave me with a list of all three vowel combinations in a given language. I'm very new to grep.

Thanks,

StWS

Comment: your `[aeiou]{3}` is not correct. it means 3 continuous vowels.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep + perl + uniq combination here:

```
cat words.txt | grep -E '[aeiou]{3}' | perl -pe 's/(.*)([aeiou]{3})(.*)/$1$2$3 $2/' | uniq -f 1
```

What it does is:

1. Grep is filtering so only words with 3 adjacent vowels are displayed
2. Perl is extracting those 3 vowels and putting them at the end of a line (after a space). On example:

   ```
   $ echo "gooad" | perl -pe 's/(.*)([aeiou]{3})(.*)/$1$2$3 $2/'
   goood ooa
   ```
3. Uniq -f 1 is comparing second column (after a space) and selecting only unique rows.

Comment: I was expanding his question, and his code is working only for words having three adjacent vowels.

Comment: To clarify the previous comment: `perl -pe 'next unless [aeiou]{3} ... ; print' words.txt`

Comment: Good point, I just happen to pipe a lot - it looks more clear to me ;)